# Directions using google maps in android studio

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, directions

How to get intermediate points between source and destination using geocoding. I have to draw the route map between the source and destination along with way points. 
I read posts about using Google Maps Directions API to retrieve the way-points. Can someone please help me with the coding ! 
Also, could you please suggest a back-end database for google maps?
I am using Android Studio. API level 21.

Comment: There is an example code here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/  For database, I would suggest using Google Fusion table https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/getting_started

Comment: I need an example code for coding in java... Set start point and end point. The response I expect should be more like the navigation service provided by google maps. Thank you for your help.